# How can you pin position of widgets in the lotus notes sidebar panel

Tags: widget, lotus-notes, sidebar

I like for my Lotus Notes client to open with just the settings and preferences that I want. One thing I always do is position and open the sidebar widgets that I will use throughout the day.

I cannot find any way to pin the widgets in the positions that I want.

Is this not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no need to pin them, as they persist across restarts.